# XQuery Invalid entity reference error caused by "&amp;" entity reference

Tags: xquery, marklogic, entityreference

I'm trying to run this line `xdmp:unquote(concat('<info>', string( $paragraph) , '</info>'))` but I've got the following error: `xdmp:unquote("<info>LEARNING &amp; MEMORY</info>") -- Invalid entity reference " " at line 1`. It seems like this entity reference `&amp;` is causing the problem. I tried to remove it using `replace` function but it still present. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds a bit like unquote is unnecessary..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you have something like this-

```
let $paragraph := <p>LEARNING &amp; MEMORY</p>
return
xdmp:unquote(fn:concat('<info>', fn:string($paragraph),'</info>'))
```

And that the result you want is XML that looks like-

```
<info>LEARNING & MEMORY</info>
```

The ampersand is definitely the issue and the workaround is to use the "repair-full" option. This example works:

```
let $paragraph := <p>LEARNING &amp; MEMORY</p>
let $contents := xdmp:unquote($paragraph, "", "repair-full")
return
<info>{$contents}</info>
```